# Varnish - how to know if a user is logged in?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

What would be best way to know if a User is Logged In?

1. one is on the basis of some (isLogin=yes) cookie. I dont find it reliable because any user can set the cookie on his browser and get access to restricted content.
2. Can we test the value of encrypted session id set at User's end, at the Varnish somehow?
3. Can HTTP Auth Headers help someway?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your needs, the traditional approach is to test for a cookie and let the backend server to determine whether it's valid or not...

You can even read a PHP session directly from Varnish with a little black magic[1], but I think it's out the scope of a site like stackoverflow.

[1] http://systemsarchitect.net/reading-php-session-from-varnish-cache/